# Jenkins Slack Automation

Tags: jenkins, slack

Is there a better and simple way to automate the Jenkins Slack Integration. I am trying to automate Jenkins pipeline script with Slack and the slack channel as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

@Unlimited To post notifications to a Slack channel, Jenkins needs the 'Slack Plugin'. You can do this from the Jenkins dashboard and find the 'Manage Jenkins' option in the left pane. Select the 'Manage Plugins' option and choose the 'Available' tab. Search for the 'Slack Notification' plugin and install it.

Hopefully, you’ve already created your Slack account. If not, [click here](https://slack.com/intl/en-in/) to get started. Once you have a Slack account, configure the Jenkins integration by using [Jenkins CI](https://slack.com/signin?redir=%2Fservices%2Fnew%2Fjenkins-ci#/signin). After configuration, click on 'Manage Jenkins' again in the left navigation and go to 'Configure System'. Find the 'Slack' section and add the following values:

Workspace: {TEAM-SUBDOMAIN}

Credential: {INTEGRATION-TOKEN-CREDENTIAL-ID}

Default channel / member id: {CHANNEL-NAME}

If you’d like, you can create a secret text credential by clicking the 'Add' button. You can also test the Jenkins and Slack integration by clicking the 'Test Connection' button.